# in Emacs, how to direct message-mode to delay sending?

Tags: emacs, cron, launchd

In Emacs, I use message-mode to send email messages. Is there a way to delay the sending of email messages until a specified time or a certain number of hours? Maybe through some Emacs invocation of cron or launchd?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `message-mode` in Gnus, you can delay the article with `C-c C-j` (`gnus-delay-article`) instead of sending it with `C-c C-c`.  Here's the link to the [manual page on delayed articles](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/gnus/Delayed-Articles.html).

If you're not using Gnus, [this link](http://teaching.sociology.ul.ie/bhalpin/wordpress/?p=236) suggests a more involved way to do it (YMMV).